# Compatibility of Platform Builder for Windows Embedded Compact 7 with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-embedded-compact

Is Platform Builder for Windows Embedded Compact 7 compatible with any other version of Visual Studio other than Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

Platform Builder 7 requires Visual Studio 2008.